# Execute script/function on each iteration of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat on an element like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="aSize in BC.aOutputSizesArr" style="width:{{aSize}}px; height:{{aSize}}px;">
    {{aSize}}
    <canvas/>
    <script>alert({{aSize}})</script>
</div>
```

So basically on every repeat, i need to draw to the canvas based on the value of `aSize`, is it possible to execute a function on every iteration of `ng-repeat`? I tried putting that `script` tag in there, but it doesnt work.

Comment: make it a directive like `<my-canvas aSzie></my-canvas>`?

Comment: Thanks @jorg but what i mean to do is I want to run a function every time, for example it should `alert` the size on every time something is added.

Comment: Yes, but you execute a function in a directive. That's what they're for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9kmj1fhv/2/) of what I mean with using a directive.

This directive:

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('alerter', function () {
    return {
        model: {
            size: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            alert(attrs.size)
        }
    };
});
```

Used like:

```
<alerter size=10>alert 10</alerter>
<alerter size=15>alert 15</alerter>
```

Will execute.

Comment: Holy hell that is amazing! Thank you jorg!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **custom directive** or the **directive** [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)
and pass a function from the controller.

This directive will execute once the tag is created by the ngRepeat.

> ```
> <canva ng-init="function()"/> <!-- function from $scope -->
> ```

Comment: Ah nginit is much easier thank you so much alvaro! Is there anyway to refer to the element from that `function`? Like my goal is to draw to that canvas, I cant seem to do `this.width` to get `canvas.width`

Comment: Hey @Alvaro do you know how to access the element from within the `ng-init`? Like I want to get and set some attributes on that html element.

Comment: you can pass an $index value and make it the id. will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

As @Jorg said, create a directive:

```
.directive('myCanvas', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            size: '=size'
        },
        template: '<canvas></canvas>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            alert(scope.size);
        }
    };
});
```

Then inside your `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="aSize in BC.aOutputSizesArr">
    {{aSize}}
    <my-canvas size="aSize"/>
</div>
```

This was quickly written and untested, but hopefully you get the idea. Just remember that the example above is just one way of binding, depending on your requirements for `aSize` (like can it be changed dynamically, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="app in appList" ng-init="getActivationFunction(app)"> <!-- function from $scope -->
    <td><h4> {{ app.Name }} </h4></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ app.ava_img }}"/> </td>
</tr>
```

in controller call the below function ...

```
$scope.getActivationFunction = function(modelRecieve) {
  Service.getServiceDate(modelRecieve.name)
    .then(function(response) {
       var date = response.data.image;  
       $scope.app.ava_img = date;
     },
   // ...
};
```