# How call a function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try execute a  function  at the same time  of ng-repeat to be able  use the index of the repeat itself. But in this moment only execute  the last time.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in arraysemanas" ng-init="add_days($index)">
    <a class="item item-icon-left fecha" href="#">
        <i class="icon calendar"></i>
        <p class="date_c">{{CurrentDate_1|  date:' EEEE dd MMMM'}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469628/execute-script-function-on-each-iteration-of-ng-repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in arraysemanas">
    <a class="item item-icon-left fecha" href="#">
        <i class="icon calendar"></i>
        <p class="date_c">{{CurrentDate_1|  date:' EEEE dd MMMM'}}</p>
        {{ add_days($index) }}
    </a>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
add_days(index) {
    days += index; // or whatever you need to do
    return '';
}
```